# Trouble installing two php packages on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, debian, raspberry-pi, geos, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to install geos with php5-geos, but it calls for two missing packages:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ sudo apt-get install php5-geosReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-geos : Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but 3.3.3-1.1 is to be installed
             Depends: phpapi-20131226
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try and install either package, I have trouble:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ sudo apt-get install libgeos-c1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgeos-c1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ sudo apt-get install phpapi-20131226
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package phpapi-20131226 is a virtual package provided by:
  php5-common 5.6.6+dfsg-2 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'phpapi-20131226' has no installation candidate
```

I have PHP version - PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u3

I have both wheezy and jessie in my sources as I wanted to install MariaDB FROM Jessie in order to support the geos module:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Anyone see what's going awry here? I am a bit of a beginner here...

Comment: Check `libgeos-c1` version (`-v` maybe?), you can also request to install a specific version `sudo apt-get install libgeos-c1=3.3.3-1.1`

Comment: Managed to get rid of the first error with your help, but still can't get the second package ( phpapi-20131226 ) done...

Comment: Re-run `sudo apt-get update` before attempting `php-api` =)